# Demonstrating use of Doxygen in a Doxygen Code Block

Tags: c, markdown, doxygen

I am creating some documentation using Doxygen that requires indicating 'best practices' for Doxygen usage in a specific context.

I have some documentation takes the following form:
(Note that I am using the Markdown extension of Doxygen)

```
Best practices for documenting
==============================

Do it like this:

   /**
    * @defgroup my_new_group My first Doxygen Group
    * 
    * a brief desc.
    */
   ...
```

What happens is that the Markdown pre-processor processes the Doxygen commands first before the Markdown processor operates.

Are there any options to demonstrate example Doxygen usage using Doxygen?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand exactly the question.

In any cases, to have doxygen commands in the documentation itself, these will need to be escaped.

Either use `@verbatim xxx @endverbatim` to output blocks as is, or escape doxygen commands with `\@`

Answer (score -1):

In the Doxygen manual it specifies how to `define` groups and then how to add to the defined groups:

> ```
> To define a group, you should put the \defgroup command in a special 
> comment block. The first argument of the command is a label that should 
> uniquely identify the group. The second argument is the name or title of 
> the group as it should appear in the documentation. (allowing you to use 
> lower-case as the initial group name)
> ```

So you should define your groups with something simalar to the following:

```
/** Group Defines
 * @\defgroup foobar foobar
 */
```

and throughout the code, to add a function, etc.. to that your could use something like the following:

```
/**
 * @addtogroup foobar
 * @{
 *     (some documentation elements...)
 * @}
 */
```